# Request.get Returns no Response Value

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I am new to coding with Python and I'm trying to start a web scraping project. When trying to run `requests.get(url)` I am not getting a response object.

For example

```py
Import requests

r = requests.get(URL)
```

I get no response object. I am under the impression that i should get a response of 200, but nothing is coming up. All i see is "Process code finished with exit code 0," so it ran but nothing showed up. I've tried other examples/URL examples from the internet with the same result. I realize this may seem like a NOOB thing to ask but any help would be appreciated. My resource for web scraping information is from Web Scraping With Python.

Thanks

Comment: See if you can follow this http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/ and figure it out

Comment: In your code "import" starts with a capital letter.

Comment: Sorry, It is lowercase in my actual code but uppercase here because of auto correct on my computer. I will keep this in mind for the future though, thank you.